# viewDidAppear called on a viewcontroller which is being dismissed in iOS8

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiviewcontroller, ios8

Let us assume ParentViewcontroller as P, FirstViewController as V1 and SecondViewController as V2.

I'm presenting V1 from P then V2 from V1. Now I want to go directly to P. For this I'm using

```
[self.presentingViewController.presentingViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];
```

This works fine in iOS7. But in iOS8 I'm facing an issue(don't know whether it is issue or not) when doing this. That is V1's viewDidAppear method is being called and also its view glitches on the screen for a fraction of second.

Is this iOS8 feature or bug?. Is there any alternative way to do this?

ViewControllers presenting code.

From P, where P is a pushed viewcontroller,

```
ViewController1 *v1 = [[ViewController1 alloc] init];      
[self presentViewController:v1 animated:NO completion:nil];
```

From V1,

```
ViewController2 *v2 = [[ViewController2 alloc] init];
[self presentViewController:v2 animated:NO completion:nil];
```

Comment: I don't know if it will make any difference, but dismissModalViewControllerAnimated: was depreciated a long time ago, you should be using dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion:.

Comment: Thank you @rdelmar. It was a copy paste issue. Copied an old code. Edited my question :).

Comment: this doesn't look like a bug to me. That should be expected based on what you are doing. How are you presenting the view controllers? Post the presentation code

Comment: @Lefteris added the presenting code in my question.

Comment: I would consider this a bug, but who knows what Apple thinks. I noticed that V1's view only flashed on screen in the iPhone 6 and 6+ simulators, but not the 5 or 4s ones (I can't test on a device because I have an iPhone 4). If I do the dismissal with animation, then I do see V1's view no matter which simulator I use. However, viewDidAppear was called when testing on any of the simulators regardless of using animation or not. That method is not called in iOS 7 using Xcode 5. I also tried using an unwind segue to go back to the initial controller, and that method also shows the same problem.

Comment: @iCanCode I face this issue today on iOS8.  The workaround is to tell V1 not to do stuff in `viewDidAppear` in this case

Answer (score 0):

Can you use your V1 embed in NavigationController (NV) ? In this way, you can push your V2.
Then you can pop to V1 or dismiss NV to P.

Comment: Nope! I cant. I'm able to goto P. My problem is when I goto P directly from V2, V1's view glitches for a fraction of second.

Answer (score 0):

After spending a lot of time in researching ended up by patching the issue.

What I did is, before dismissing the ViewController(V2) I captured a screen-shot of ParentViewcontroller(P) and added it to the application window. Then removed the image from the window after the ViewController(V2)'s dismissal.

```
CGRect deviceRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];

UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(deviceRect.size, NO, [UIScreen mainScreen].scale);
CGContextRef contextRef = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextTranslateCTM(contextRef, -deviceRect.origin.x, -deviceRect.origin.y);
[[self.presentingViewController.presentingViewController.view layer] renderInContext:contextRef];
UIImage *capturedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

UIImageView *windowImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, deviceRect.size.width, deviceRect.size.height)];
[windowImageView setImage:capturedImage];
[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] addSubview:windowImageView];

[self.presentingViewController.presentingViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:^
{
      [windowImageView removeFromSuperview];
}];
```

Answer (score 0):

The fact that 'viewWill/DidAppear' is invoked when you dismiss V1 is logical as technically V1 is exposed in the modal dismissal of the top viewController (V2), if only for long enough that UIKit then gets tasked to remove the next underlying viewController (e.g. V1).

My guess would be the V1 visual glitch in iOS8 is not a bug and more to do with how iOS deals with dismissal of a modal-inside-a-modal in iOS8. Since no documentation exists for that situation its actual behavior can legitimately change from iOS to iOS.

I think one way to do what you want to do, keep your backwards compatibility to older iOS's, and use API's with documented behavior, would be using code such as below (perhaps as a category on UIViewController). to animate V1 up, then later simply remove it (#2 below). V2 could probably be animated up inside V1 using the standard iOS 'presentViewController', but you could also use method #1 for it.

One note is that since you are adding V1.view as a subview to P instead of through the UIViewController modal system, you will lose the automated viewWill/DidAppear calls in V1. So you would need to invoke those manually. In this example they are invoked in the 'animate up' category method.

This isn't code I'm actually using, but I've done similar things in the past. So be a little careful and please comment if errors are found....assumes ARC:

Hope this helps.

```
    //1. animate V1 up (executed from P)
    ViewController  * V1 = [[ViewController1 alloc] init];
    //place V1 view below bottom of P
    V1.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, UI_phone_height, UI_phone_width, UI_phone_height);
    [self.view addSubview: V1.view]; //'self' is P
    [V1 customAnimateUpCategory];

    // >> method #1 in a UIViewController category
    - (void) customAnimateUpCategory {

            //...optional
            [self viewWillAppear];

            [UIView animateWithDuration:0.4
                     animations:^ {
                         //animate V1.view up
                         self.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, UI_phone_width, UI_phone_height);
                     }
                     completion:^ (BOOL finished) {
                         if (finished) {
                             //...optional
                             [self viewDidAppear];
                         }
                     }
            ];
    }


    //2. make V1/V2 disappear without animation (executed from V2)
    //'V1' is weakly held in V2 as an IVAR
    [self.V1 removeViewCategory]

    // >> method #2 in a UIViewController category
    - (void) removeViewCategory {
            [self.view removeFromSuperview];//should remove and release V1/V2 glitch free!!
    }
```